# Calculating a straight from a modified deck

Tags: probability, poker

You are given a deck of cards with 4 suits and 15 ranks, compute the probability of a "Straight", which is five cards in sequence, but not all from the same suit.

I have calculated that the number of possible hands is $ C(60, 5)$. Also the number of different rank I can get is $ C(11,1) $. However I am having trouble understanding the following question: "The suits can be anything other than all equal, so the number of possibilities for the suits of a straight is"
If I was just calculating the number of possible straights I would have simply done $$4^5 * C(11,1)$$. Hence, I'd assume the question is asking for how many different suits combinations I can have. I tried $4^5$ and $4$. But both answers are wrong.

Comment: You only need to eliminate from the set of all possible straights (without checking suits) the cases where all suits are equal.

Comment: Can you please expand on that?

Comment: You have the number of all possible hands, and the number of all possible hands that are straights. Now calculate the number of all possible straights with all suits equal, then subtract this number to the total of straights. After divide this quantity by the total of hands and voilá!

Comment: 11 is wrong unless you are not playing ace as low also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a deck of $4$ suits and $15$ different ranks for a total of $60$ cards. The hand is composed by $5$ cards.

If the hand is composed by consecutive ranks then it is a straight. I assume here that consecutive means that there is no cycle, by example the hand $14,15,1,2,3$ is not a straight.

Then, as the OP stated, the number of different straight by ranks is $11$, i.e. there are $11$ groups of cards, based on ranks, that are straight. From each group of straights $4$ combinations are prohibited, i.e. the straights with the same suit.

For each group of straights then there is a total of $4^5-4=1020$ valid straights. Then the probability to get a valid straight is

$$\frac{1020\cdot 11}{\binom{60}{5}}=\frac{935}{455126}\approx 0.2\%$$

Comment: This is not playing the ace as low also but OP said 11